# Fatal error when i try to install Mysqlclient Python

Tags: python

When i try to install Mysqlclient through pip i get this error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'my_config.h': No such file or directory
```

How do i fix it? Python 3.4(x64), Win7.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because you don't have the right mysql server for development (some files miss).

1. Download and install the [MySQL Community Server 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html)
2. Then retry to install **Mysqlclient** package